# Unity on 2 screens without main application menus

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, menu

I'm used to work with 2 monitors, but after switching to Unity I can **not** access the main menus of applications. The main menu panel is only displayed on one of the screens

Is there a way of dealing with this?! [(see the screenshot). No Main Menu on Unity with 2 screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONgkD.png)

Comment: try to keep questions singular in nature - feel free to ask further questions if required.  I've edited your question to reflect your key question as per the title.

Answer (score 3):

Updating Ubuntu 11.10 with the latest packages solved the problem for me. Tested on 2 TVs, and 4 Monitors in groups of 2. It even works with different resolutions.